# Django Admin StackedInline Not Loading Add Another model, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x

When I add a number of inlines to my `django admin` as shown below the `Add another {model name}` disappears. If I check the javascript console I see that I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>
> at inlines.js:20
>
> at inlines.js:295

Here's my Django admin:

```
@admin.register(models.Paper)
class PaperAdmin(BaseLiteratureAdmin):

    class EditedPaperAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = models.EditedPaper
        extra = 0

    class SupplementaryInformationAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = models.SupplementaryInformation
        extra = 0

    class PaperNotesAdminInline(BaseNotesAdminInline):
        exclude = tuple(
            i for i in BaseNotesAdminInline.exclude if i != 'paper'
        )

    class ReferencedPaperInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = models.Paper.referenced_papers.through
        extra = 0
        fk_name = 'from_paper'
        verbose_name = "Referenced Paper"
        verbose_name_plural = "Referenced Papers"

    inlines = (
        EditedPaperAdminInline, # problem
        PaperNotesAdminInline, # ok single/together
        ReferencedPaperInline, # ok single/together
        SupplementaryInformationAdminInline, # problem
        
    )
```

Here's what I'd like to see:
[image: Admin with ability to Add new model]

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image]

And I found the solution--it's to change the order of the inlines in the `inlines` list, like so:

```
inlines = (
        PaperNotesAdminInline, # ok single/together
        ReferencedPaperInline, # ok single/together
        EditedPaperAdminInline, # problem
        SupplementaryInformationAdminInline, # problem
        
    )
```

The #comments next to each inline note that the `PaperNotesAdminInline` and `ReferencedPaperInline` are both 'OK' in that the `Add another {model name}` link still appears if they are included. The other two inlines, if added in order shown in the admin model definition, result in the JavaScript error and the links disappearing for each inline. However, if I change the order to the second `inlines` list, everything loads correctly.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I has same problem on my project, on a large rich form script inline.js loads before jQuery and produces an error.
I added changed inline.js to my project folder, it checks are jQuery loaded, and if not, it waits for 300 ms, and tries again.
Patch here.

```
--- django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.js
+++ myproject/myproject/static/admin/js/inlines.js
@@ -15,7 +15,8 @@
  * Licensed under the New BSD License
  * See: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
  */
-(function($) {
+
+function start_inline($) {
     'use strict';
     $.fn.formset = function(opts) {
         var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formset.defaults, opts);
@@ -292,4 +293,16 @@
             }
         });
     });
-})(django.jQuery);
+};
+
+function start_inline_loader() {
+    try {
+        start_inline(django.jQuery);
+
+    } catch(e) {
+        console.log('no jQuery, try again after 300 mc');
+        setTimeout( function() {start_inline_loader();}, 300)
+    }
+}
+
+start_inline_loader();
```